# Why parsley don't work in Django?

Tags: django

I have a model:

```
class Users_data (models.Model):
    ...
    password = models.CharField(max_length=45, verbose_name="")
    password2 = models.CharField(max_length=45, verbose_name="")
    ...
```

And I have a form:

```
@parsleyfy
class Form_registration (ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        parsley_namespace = 'parsley'
        parsley_extras = {
            'password': {
                'minlength': "5",
            },
            'password2': {
                'equalto': "password",
                'error-message': "Your passwords not equales",
            },
            "hide_errors": {
                "show-errors": True,
            },
        }
        model = Users_data
...
    password = CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder':'New Password'}),       label="")
    password2 = CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Re-Entere Password'}), label="")
...
```

In template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/bootstrap/js/parsley.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/bootstrap/js/parsley.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script>
<form data-parsley-validate method="post" action="save_data_user/">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form_registration.as_p }}
{{ form_registration.error }}
```

But parsley don't work. Also I add 'parsley','jquery', in INSTALLED_APPS.
How solve it?
Thank for answers.

Comment: I expect you need to include jQuery before Parsley in the template. And I don't think you want both parsley.js and parsley.min.js.

Comment: I delete parsley.min.js, but no result

Comment: I refer you to the comment I made above. You need to include jquery *before* parsley. You would benefit from looking at the errors in the browser's dev tools console.

Comment: I try this                                                       <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/bootstrap/js/parsley.js"></script>

Comment: or this:  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script><code> <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/bootstrap/js/parsley.min.js"></script>